# What meta-information is contained in an image file?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, metadata, jpeg, png

I'm wondering what information is contained in an image file like JPEG or PNG.

I know that most of them contain a metadata file, but anything else other than that?

Anything relates to the license key or personal information in there?

Does software like Photoshop hide some user data in an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, Photoshop does not store any personally identifiable metadata in addition to whatever is already in the file and stored by the operating system.

This answer cannot address all packages as each is different.

Answer (score 0):

Go grab a copy of [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) for your system and experiment with some images. The info contained in the image can be as simple as the camera info, resolution, and timestamp or it could also include other data like GPS location. It really depends on the tool that created the image.

Comment: I use Photoshop most of the time. I left the File Info in PS completely blank, but i just wonder if there are hidden datas in the PNG or JPG file :)